# Beginner Java coder trying to figure out how to end a program if a question is answered no

Tags: java

In the below code I'm trying to have the program end after asking if you want to enter student data and the answer is no. Otherwise continue on through the program.

```java
package variables;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhileLoop {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data;
        double average;
        //enter names
        System.out.print("Do you want to enter student data? [y/n]");
        data = in.next();
        while (data.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) ;
        in.close();

        System.out.print("First name: ");
        String first, last;
        first = in.next();
        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        last = in.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(data.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));` <- Your loop is terminating here. You shouldn't use semicolon after it

Comment: Why are you closing in before you're finished with it? You will not be able to reopen System.in, nor use any Scanner that requires System.in.

Answer (score 0):

I have added an extra part to validate except y or n inputs.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter student data? [y/n]");
        String answer = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            return;
        } else if (!"y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            while (!"n".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && !"y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please type y or n");
                answer = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("First name: ");
        String firstName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        String lastName = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
    }
}
```